# How to work with Newline in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, jscript

I am strugling with regexp.

I am using jscript to do some replacements.

```
Find: "@@(.*): (\\.*$)"
replacewith: ",@$1@:@$2@"
```

problem I am facing is, it is adding last @ after the newline character.

It is understood that .* reaches to the end but should it match \r?\n also?

**sample input after suggestion**

text:

```
@@some text: \some text
@@sometext: \sometext
@@many such lines starts with @@
```

Result from Find: `"@@(.*): (\\.*$)"` replacewith: `",@$1@:@$2@"`

```
,@some text@:@\sometext
@
,@some text@:@\sometext
@
```

what I want:

```
,@some text@:@\sometext@
,@some text@:@\sometext@
```

Comment: can you add sample inputs and outputs to your question?

Comment: Looks like the issue is not related to [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/uC0eW4/1), nor [this one](https://regex101.com/r/uC0eW4/2).

Comment: @gurvinder372: and Wiktor, I have added the example.

Comment: Is `string` a as-is literal here or a placeholder for something else?

Comment: It is some text. Edited.

Comment: So you want to replace first two `@` with `,` and newline character with `@`? Will be helpful if you can describe your problem statement and share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net of what you have tried.

Comment: Yup. Was hard to explain!. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it works in regex101 and notepad but in script it creates probelm. I will share the script.

Comment: `.*` is *not* supposed to match a newline. So yes, this needs a [mcve].

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject I guess you will have to describe the problem statement yourself only since I would only be doing guesswork.

Comment: I have an idea: you are using a VBA regex library and perform some changes in a Word document, right? Well, even if not, try replacing `.*` with `[^\r\n]`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. I am using Jscript (scripting filesystemobject) for creating json file from rtf strings using regex. I am using @ in place of `"` to avoid difficulty `@` will be later converted to `"`.